# Workaround for R / Hive architecture mismatch?

Tags: r, architecture, hive

I have a 32-bit Hive cluster which my R session connects to via `RODBC`.

This requires me to use 32-bit R to pull data from Hive. However, both memory and a number of other packages, connections, and constraints necessitate the use of 64-bit R (and 64-bit is both my preferred and default choice of R).

Is there any way to get around this driver architecture mismatch, so that I can use 64-bit R for my pull of Hive data?

Ideally I would like to do this in a more direct fashion, but I was thinking that if nothing else perhaps I can call a 32-bit R session from the 64-bit R session and submit to it a .R script with the data pull commands? The only thing I can't figure out with this solution would be how to pass the resulting data from one R session to another without wasting time and disk space by writing the results out to an intermediate file.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a 32 / 64 bit ODBC driver issue and not an R issue?

Comment: @cory Yea I'm pretty sure. I had this issue when I first setup the cluster 18 months ago and everything indicated that I had to use 32 bit R. When I use 32 bit R it always works, when I use 64 bit R the same code gives me a message about the missing architecture. I'm not sure exactly how it works under the hood, but presumably 32 bit RODBC uses 32 bit drivers and 64 bit uses 64 bit or something like that.